# Background is stretch in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, xml, andengine

I'm developing a game using AndEngine and I've a XML file for any level...XML file has width and height and background...I use sprite for background...if image size in assets folder be big(for e.g 256*256)the screen is black and not shown any sprite...if image size be 200*200, background is shown but be drawn(stretch) and well not shown...camera_width=800 and camera_height=480
What is wrong in my code?What size do I take images in assets folder?What amounts be the width and height of my sprite?

XML file:

```
<level width="2500" height="780" background="back1">
<entity x="" y="" type=""/>
...
</level>
```

GameScene:

```
final int width = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes,
                            LevelConstants.TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH);
                    final int height = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes,
                            LevelConstants.TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_HEIGHT);
                    final String backGround = SAXUtils.getAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes, TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_BACKGROUND);

                    Sprite levelBack;

                    if (backGround
                            .equals(TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_BACKGROUND_VALUE_BACK1)) {
                        levelBack = new Sprite(0, 0,height,width,
                                resourceManager.game_back1_region, vbom) {
                            @Override
                            protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState,
                                    Camera pCamera) {
                                super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                                pGLState.enableDither();
                            }
                        };
ParallaxBackground parallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(
                                0.3f, 0.3f, 0.9f);
parallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0,levelBack));
setBackground(parallaxBackground);
```

Answer (score 0):

width and height may be different.
so when you create: levelBack = new Sprite(0, 0,height,width,.... , background will be drawn(stretch).

about black screen, I don't know alot, but line: `new ParallaxBackground(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.9f);` is backgroundColor (0.3, 0.3, 0.9)?